# Codeship restore PostgreSQL database?

Tags: postgresql, codeship

I have a small subset of our db as a dump to do integration testing. I restore it using this command:

```
pg_restore --no-acl --no-owner --verbose --create -h localhost -p 5435 -j 4 -U $PG_USER -d test latest.dump
```

The problem is that in the logs I see:

```
pg_restore: connecting to database for restore
pg_restore: processing item 5308 ENCODING ENCODING
pg_restore: processing item 5309 STDSTRINGS STDSTRINGS
pg_restore: processing item 5310 DATABASE dlq8aimf0q2pf
pg_restore: creating DATABASE dlq8aimf0q2pf
pg_restore: connecting to new database "dlq8aimf0q2pf"
pg_restore: connecting to database "dlq8aimf0q2pf" as user "postgres"
```

As you could see it tries to create "dlq8aimf0q2pf" not "test" as I specified.
Would I be able to get the database name? What ENV var is using this name?

Answer (score 0):

As said in [pg_restore doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgrestore.html) about the `--create` option :

> When this option is used, the database named with -d is used only to issue the
>   initial DROP DATABASE and CREATE DATABASE commands. **All data is restored into the
>   database name that appears in the archive.**

If you have an existing database `test` and want to restore into it, don't use `--create`.